# Dynamic change of restricted area capacity based on Agent type approaching

Tags: anylogic

the model has 2 agent types - for the first agent type the capacity when approaching the restricted aread shall be one. For the second agent type the capacity shall be 5.

**How to change the capacity dynamicly at a restriced area based on the agent approaching?**

Thanks in advance

Chris

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGa8v.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Easiest alternative would be to split the agent flow before the restricted area by agent type: Use a `SelectOutput` object and decide the exit to use using `agent instanceof AgentTypeX` as a condition.

Downstream, create 2 restricted areas and set the capacity according to the type flowing through.

Comment: Hello Benjamin, ooooh I understand! Your solution will do it - Thank you for your help!

Comment: no problem. Ask good, clear questions and you get good answers :)